# Field cannot be deleted because it is being used as relationship key?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, fields-attributes, delete

I want to delete some fields of `featureclasses`, but when I run the code  `FeatureClass.DeleteField(Field)` it works well for some `featureclasses` but after some time it gives an error such as:

> **The field cannot be deleted because it is being used as a relationship key.**

Answer (score 3):

The layers where this error is occurring must be a part of a [Relationship Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Benefits_of_relationship_classes/004t00000003000000/).

In ArcGIS, this is a join between two `feature classes` or tables that is being maintained by the Geodatabase.  It can be either a **one to one**, **one to many** or **many to many** relationship.  It is based on Primary and Foreign key fields, which contain unique identifiers to link the tables together.  Since the Relationship Class is a type of object maintained by the geodatabase, the Key fields are [properties of this class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Relationship_class_properties/004t00000004000000/) and are likely going to be protected from deletion.

What you will need to do to solve this problem is make a **list** of those feature classes where an error is being raised, and find the `relationship class` or `classes` associated with them.  You will have to **delete** those `relationship classes` in order for the lock to be removed from the particular field in the feature class.